# ArcGIS find conflict between layer and geometry

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-server, arcgis-js-api

I have a problem I could use some help with. In our application we have multiple FeatureLayers and on some of these layers a user can draw new objects.

When a user draws a new object, lets call it a tent (any type of Geometry), I need to check if the position is valid. The object is valid when it does not consume the same position as a building. The buildings are stored on a separate featureLayer that is stored on a MapServer (and loaded in the browser). The drawing, the tent, is only stored locally (for now).

So to get to the point.. what is think I need is a service that finds the distance between all objects on a layer(the buildings) and the object that is drawn at-the-moment..

I did have a look at the [SummarizeNearby](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/analysis/api-reference/summarize-nearby.htm) services but at this moment we don’t have the license for it. Then I had a look at the [GeometryService](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/geometryservice-amd.html) and I would like to know if this is the correct way to do it..

I think it is possible to use the difference or intersect method of the GeometryService to find the difference between all the graphic/geometries on the buildings-layer and the drawn-object. If the difference is the same size as the graphics in the buildings-layer, then there is no conflict. But if the result is different then the buildings-layer, then the buildings-layer did contain the object that is just drawn, and there-for the drawn object is not valid.

Please let me now if this is the way to go, or if there are other ways to calculate/find objects that intersect/overlap.

Many thanks!

Nico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just looking to figure out that any of the 'tents' overlap any of the buildings, I would suggest doing a query on the building service using the tent geometry as your spatial filter.

Here's [the documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/query-amd.html) on using the `Query` and `QueryTask` objects in the API. You could play around with the various spatial relationships to see what works for you. Set the geometry property equal to the tent geometry, create a `QueryTask` and call `executeForCount`. The callback function will give you the count of features, or in this case, buildings, that match the spatial query you just did.

Here's a [quick fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wv7xa3jg/) I threw together.

Comment: That's how I did it indeed. Works fine.